# Where can I find the GCC 9 implementation of std::chrono::system_clock::now()?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, system-clock, gcc9

The `chrono` system header (`/usr/include/c++/9/chrono`) declares, but does not define, the `static` `now()` functions of its clocks. I also do not see an include that looks relevant. Where are these functions implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where are these functions implemented?

In your C++ standard library implementation.

GNU compiler is shipped with [GNU C++ library - libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/libstdc++/manual/). Inside gcc source tree, you may find [libstdc++-v3/chrono.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc#L52) file with the implementation of `chrono::now()` function.